# Class 'DOMDocument' not found but works fine locally

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, laravel-5, amazon-ec2

l am currently running an app locally using homestead and it works fine. l just got it onto an ec2 server and things are breaking, for some reason l keep getting Class 'DOMDocument' not found but works fine locally.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds to me like your ec2 instance is not meeting the requirements for Laravel. Have you installed all of the necessary php modules listed in the requirements section of the install docs?

Comment: From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/dom.requirements.php): *This extension requires the libxml PHP extension. This means that passing in --enable-libxml is also required, although this is implicitly accomplished because libxml is enabled by default.* Double-check that you have libxml installed and enabled.